# Detecting that a child process was killed because the OS is out of memory

Tags: c++, windows, macos, unix, memory

I'm working on a large-scale application that spawns numerous processes for dealing with various tasks. In some situations, the OS will kill one of my processes because of memory pressure. That's ok, it's entirely expected, the parent process handles this gracefully.

What I'd like to know is find out why a process was killed. If it was killed because of memory pressure, I want to respawn the treatment a little later. If it was killed for any other reason – because, say, of an assertion failure or an out of bounds memory access, I want to log and investigate.

So, here's my question: how do you find out that a child process was killed because the OS needed the memory?

Question applies to:

- Windows;
- MacOS;
- Linux;
- (for bonus points, I'm also interested in Android, but that's not my priority).

Processes are **not** running as root/admin.

Comment: *In some situations, the OS will kill one of my processes because of memory pressure.*  What a horribly unreliable configuration.  What if the OS decides to kill your parent process?  And people wonder why their systems have nine 5's of reliability instead of the required five 9s...

Comment: Well, we're working with the OS on making sure that it kills the children processes rather than the parent process. But how else would you handle out of memory conditions on your Operating System?

Comment: Disable the [out-of-fuel, err, out-of-memory killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/), and disable memory overcommit, configure the system with a proper amount of swap space so the OS doesn't have to **LIE** to a process by telling it it can use all this memory and then killing it should the process dare have the temerity to actually use the memory **the OS SAID IT COULD**.  "Ooops, sorry, I **LIED** about how much memory you get to use!  **HAAA HAAA**!  You're **DEAD!!!**" is a horrible paradigm if you want reliability.

Comment: Ah, well, that's how all user OSes work these days. I'm not going to write a new OS just for this :)

Comment: *Ah, well, that's how all user OSes work these days.* No, it is not. You can actually configure systems to be reliable. And what are you doing running production processes on what you term a "user os" in the first place?

Comment: Can't you have a better design to handle this? Surely you know the nature of your application better than the OS. As a start, can you try to determine your system capacity 
 in terms of the number of parallel tasks? Limit the max memory usage for each task. Once you're able to determine the capacity, design a job dispatching logic to control the load. You shouldn't rely on OS randomly killing your processes.

Comment: "You shouldn't rely on OS randomly killing your processes." It's a defense in depth. There are already several layers of defense against out-of-memory, that's the last one.

Comment: "And what are you doing running production processes on what you term a "user os" in the first place?" It's a end user-oriented application. It goes where the end user is.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can read the `syslog` to find out whether a process was killed by the OS. you can investigate it by reading the `syslog` (/var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog on some distributions) or via the `dmesg` command.
If you spawned the process you can also detect that it was killed with the `SIGKILL(9)` signal, as opposed to the `SIGSEGV(11)` signal that corresponds to the app crashing all by itself, and `SIGINT(2)`/`SIGTERM(15)` that means that the applications was aked to terminate gracefully.

Regarding Windows, I only know that this type of monitoring can be enabled via the `Application Event Log`. There's a [GUI Application](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/supportingwindows/2013/05/01/what-killed-my-process/) that can help you set it up.

Comment: You have no guarantees whatsoever that the message will be in syslog before the process gets SIGKILLed and, in fact, most sysloggers will intentionally delay an individual message from getting flushed to syslog in order to combine duplicate messages. This is not going to work reliably.

Comment: I'm ok with the files not being updated immediately. I'm a bit more nervous about the files not always being present or readable. But yeah, if I don't find a better solution, I'll definitely look at this, thanks!

Comment: That's why the detection of `SIGKILL(9)` is so important.

Comment: But I don't think that I can be certain that `SIGKILL` means out of memory, right?

Comment: Also, @Shloim regarding your addition wrt to the GUI Application– thanks. I'm not interested in GUI solutions, but I'll dig if I can find the data that this application uses.

Comment: `SIGKILL` doesn't mean memory. `SIGKILL` is an indecation that the application was killed forcefully and not gracefully via `SIGTERM`. Anyone with enough priveleges can do it to your process, but if you don't see `SIGKILL` you can be certain that it wasn't the kernel. Sometimes it may be enough for your application's logic.

Comment: The GUI application is an example of an app using the event log monitoring API to do this, I'm guessing that you can easily do the same.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's going to be easy, as it apparently requires tweaking the registry base. That's not something I can afford to do.

Answer (score 0):

When the OS intervenes in the execution of a process in order to kill, it does so via signals.

What you can do (on IX based/like platforms) is -- dmesg.

It outputs the kernel activity logs.
From there, you can identify the signal that was sent to your process.

For example this code below --

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    char *p = NULL;

    printf ("\n%c", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Causes this obtained from dmesg --

```
[8478285.606105] crash.out[16830]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000400531 sp 00007fffc373b090 error 4 in crash.out[400000+1000]
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but there's unfortunately no message `SIGOOM` that I know of :)

Comment: Perhaps this can help? https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html